# Who is this vigalante hired by Tobias Church in Arrow S05E05?

Tags: character, arrowverse, comic-adaptation, arrow

In Arrow S05E05, Tobias Church hires a vigilante to kill Green Arrow.

[image]

He even attempted the deed:

[image]

But who is this vigilante, is he some straight from the comic book character like [Human Target](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Target) or did he just come out of air for the show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as we can tell, this character was invented for the show, though the writers don't seem to think so.

In the end credits, the character is identified as Scimitar:

[image]

Although [the writers claim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hQsCgSvyrs) that this character is a "big DC universe character", there's no DC character I could find named Scimitar. There is a [*Marvel* character](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Scimitar_(Earth-616)) named scimitar that bears some resemblance to the character in this show, but I doubt that's who they intended.

It's also possible they just got the character's name wrong.

Comment: When I first saw the character, I thought it was Deathstroke again, since the armor is so similar.

Comment: @Thunderforge That's also what I thought. But I was kinda expecting the son of Slade somehow aged or not aged, because of Legends of Tomorrow episode, where the similar guy appeared. :-)